# Are there any responsive email frameworks that support gmail client?

Tags: html, css, gmail, responsive

gmail client does not support media queries.  Are there any responsive email frameworks that support responsive designs in Gmail email client?

Comment: that doesn't answer my question,  does this support gmail?

Comment: it doesnt look like they support gmail.  https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/issues/1280,  any other frameworks that support that?

Comment: MJML does support gmail, I've just used it in a project. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would use MJML or Foundation for Emails.